# Word2Vec + LSTM on API Sequence

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm, word2vec

I am trying to apply word2Vec and LSTM on a dataset that contains files' API trace log including API function calls and their parameters for a binary classification.

The data looks like:

```
File_ID,    Label,   API Trace log
 1,           M,      kernel32 LoadLibraryA kernel32.dll
                      kernel32 GetProcAddress MZ\x90 ExitProcess
                      ...

 2,           V,     kernel32 GetModuleHandleA RPCRT4.dll
                     kernel32 GetCurrentThreadId d\x8B\x0D0 POINTER POINTER
                     ...
```

The API trace including: module name, API function name, parameters (that separated by blank space)

Take first API trace of file 1 as example, kernel32 is the module name, LoadLibraryA is function name, kernel32.dll is parameter. Each API trace is separated by \n so that each line represents a API sequence information sequentially.

Firstly I trained a word2vec model based on the line sentence of all API trace log. There are about 5k API function calls, e.g. LoadLibraryA, GetProcAddress. However, because parameter value could be vary, the model becomes quite big (with 300,000 vocabulary) after including those parameters.

After that, I trained a LSTM by applying word2vec's embedding_wrights, the model structure looks like:

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Embedding(output_dim=vocab_dim, input_dim=n_symbols, \
                mask_zero=False, weights=[embedding_weights], \
                trainable=False))
model.add(LSTM(dense_dim,kernel_initializer='he_normal', dropout=0.15, 
recurrent_dropout=0.15, implementation=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[early_stopping, parallel_check_cb])
```

The way I get embedding_weights is to create a matrix, for each vocabulary in word2vec model, map the index of the word in the model, to it's vector

```
def create_embedding_weights(model, max_index=0):
    # dimensionality of your word vectors
    num_features = len(model[model.vocab.keys()[0]])
    n_symbols = len(model.vocab) + 1  # adding 1 to account for 0th index (for masking)
    # Only word2vec feature set
    embedding_weights = np.zeros((max(n_symbols + 1, max_index + 1), num_features))
    for word, value in model.vocab.items():
        embedding_weights[value.index, :] = model[word]

    return embedding_weights
```

For training data, what I did is that for each word in API call, convert the actual word to the index of word2vec model so that it's consistent to the index in embedding_weights above. `e.g. kernel32 -> 0,  LoadLibraryA -> 1, kernel32.dll -> 2. GetProcAddress -> 4,  MZ\x90 -> 5, ExitProcess ->6`

So the train data for file 1 looks like `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.  Noted, I didn't do line split for each API trace. As a result, the model may not know where is the start and end of API trace?  And the training accuracy of the model is pretty bad - accuracy is 50% :(

**My question is that, when prepare the training and validation dataset, should I also split the line when mapping the actual words to their index**? then The above training data would be changed to following, each API trace is separated by a line, and maybe padd the missing value to -1 which doesn't exist in word2vec's indexes.

```
[[0, 1, 2, -1]
 [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Meanwhile I am using a very simple structure for training, while word2vec model is quite big, any suggestion on structure would also be appreciated.

Comment: @Marcin Możejko，could you please help to shed the green lights? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would at least split the trace lines in three:

- Module (make a dictionary and an embedding)
- Function (make a dictionary and an embedding)
- Parameters (make a dictionary and an embedding - see details later)

Since this is a very specific application, I believe it would be best to keep the embeddings trainable (the whole point of the embeddings is to create meaningful vectors, and the meanings depend a lot on the model that is going to use them. Question: how did you create the word2vec model? From what data does it learn?).

This model would have more inputs. All of them as integers from zero to max dictionary index. Consider using `mask_zero=True` and padding all files to `maxFileLines`.

```
moduleInput = Input(maxFileLines,) 
functionInput = Input(maxFileLines,)
```

For the parameters, I'd probably make a subsequence as if the list of parameters were a sentence. (Again, mask_zero=True, and pad up to `maxNumberOfParameters`)

```
parametersInput = Input(maxFileLines, maxNumberOfParameters)
```

Function and module embeddings:

```
moduleEmb = Embedding(.....mask_zero=True,)(moduleInput)    
functionEmb = Embedding(.....mask_zero=True)(functionInput)
```

Now, for the parameters, I though of creating a sequence of sequences (maybe this is too much). For that, I first transfer the lines dimension to the batch dimension and work with only length = maxNumberOfParameters:

```
paramEmb = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,(-1,maxNumberOfParameters)))(parametersInput)
paramEmb = Embedding(....,mask_zero=True)(paramEmb)
paramEmb = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,(-1,maxFileLines,embeddingSize)))(paramEmb)
```

Now we concatenate all of them in the last dimension and we're ready to get into the LSTMs:

```
joinedEmbeddings = Concatenate()([moduleEmb,functoinEmb,paramEmb])
out = LSTM(...)(joinedEmbeddings)
out = ......

model = Model([moduleInput,functionInput,parametersInput], out)
```

### How to prepare the inputs

With this model, you need three separate inputs. One for the module, one for the function and one for the parameters.

These inputs will contain only indices (no vectors). And they don't need a previous word2vec model. Embeddings are word2vec transformers.

So, get the file lines and split. First we split by commas, then we split the API calls by spaces:

```
import numpy as np

#read the file
loadedFile = open(fileName,'r')
allLines = [l.strip() for l in loadedFile.readlines()] 
loadedFile.close()

#split by commas
splitLines = []
for l in allLines[1:]: #use 1 here only if you have headers in the file
    splitLines.append (l.split(','))
splitLines = np.array(splitLines)

#get the split values and separate ids, targets and calls
ids = splitLines[:,0]
targets = splitLines[:,1]
calls = splitLines[:,2]

#split the calls by space, adding dummy parameters (spaces) to the max length
splitCalls = []
for c in calls:
    splitC = c.strip().split(' ')

    #pad the parameters (space for dummy params)
    for i in range(len(splitC),maxParams+2):
        splitC.append(' ') 

    splitCalls.append(splitC)

splitCalls = np.array(splitCalls)

modules = splitCalls[:,0]
functions = splitCalls[:,1]
parameters = splitCalls[:,2:] #notice the parameters have an extra dimension
```

Now lets make the indices:

```
modIndices, modCounts = np.unique(modules,return_counts=True)
funcIndices, funcCounts = np.unique(functions,return_counts=True)

#for de parameters, let's flatten the array first (because we have 2 dimensions)
flatParams = parameters.reshape((parameters.shape[0]*parameters.shape[1],))
paramIndices, paramCounts = np.unique(flatParams,return_counts=True)
```

These will create a list of unique words and get their counts. Here you can customize which words you're going to group in "another word" class. (Maybe based on the counts, if the count is too little, make it an "another word").

Let's then make the dictionaries:

```
def createDic(uniqueWords):
    dic = {}
    for i,word in enumerate(uniqueWords):
         dic[word] = i + 1 # +1 because we want to reserve the zeros for padding     
    return dic
```

Just take care with the parameters, because we used a dummy space there:

```
moduleDic = createDic(modIndices)
funcDic = createDic(funcIndices)
paramDic = createDic(paramIndices[1:]) #make sure the space got the first position here    
paramDic[' '] = 0
```

Well, now we just replace the original values:

```
moduleData = [moduleDic[word] for word in modules]
funcData = [funcDic[word] for word in functions]
paramData = [[paramDic[word] for word in paramLine] for paramLine in parameters]
```

Pad them:

```
for i in range(len(moduleData),maxFileLines):
    moduleData.append(0)
    funcData.append(0)
    paramData.append([0] * maxParams)
```

Do this for every file, and store in a list of files:

```
moduleTrainData = []  
functionTrainData = []
paramTrainData = []
for each file do the above and:
    moduleTrainData.append(moduleData)
    functionTrainData.append(funcData)
    paramTrainData.append(paramData)

moduleTrainData = np.asarray(moduleTrainData)
functionTrainData = np.asarray(functionTrainData)
paramTrainData = np.asarray(paramTrainData)
```

That's all for the inputs.

```
model.fit([moduleTrainData,functionTrainData,paramTrainData],outputLabels,...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions. I trained word2Vec model from API  Trace Log, the model takes every line (module + function + parameter) as lineSentence input.  is maxFileLines the max number of API traces across all the files? e.g. file 1 has 1000 API function calls, file n has 5000 API function calls, so the maxFileLines is 5000.

Comment: I am complete newbie so please bare with me for my stupid questions :) The moduleInput, functionInput and parametersInput  defines the shape of input data to the model. So when preparing the Training and validation data, I will still need to convert/map the actual word to the directory index? e.g kernel32's index is 0, so in training data, use 0 instead of kernel32. My question is that how does kernel32's vector come in play in the model?

Comment: Yes, you should be using three separate arrays. One array for module input, one functionInput and another for parameterInput. And yes, they should be integer indices. (But spare the 0 for padding, start the real words from 1). The `Embedding` layers in the model are responsible for transforming the indices into vectors. (The difference is that you don't have a previous group of weights for the embedding, you will let the embedding train itfelf for the best vectors possible).

Comment: Yes too, `maxFileLines` is 5000 according to what you say. When you create the input arrays, complete the files that have less than 5000 lines with zeros (and don't forget to turn on the `mask_zero` in the embeddings).

Comment: Thanks again. For any missing value, I should pad with 0 in three inputs. For instance some function calls don't have any parameters, so in parametersInput I will need to pad 0 as it's parameters's value so that the order of parameters match the order of function call?  e.g. function getProcessID doesn't have parameters, it's 11th function call of file 3, so the 11th parametersInput for this file is all 0s to match this function?

Comment: Yes. But maybe having the entire dimension filled with zeros will cause an error (not sure). If an error due to that occurs, maybe you should not mask the zeros for the parameters and consider zero as an actual "missing" parameter.

Comment: I found that in current word2vec dictionary, kernel32's index is 0, so I might need to pad with other values by some rules:

Comment: When I convert the training data from actual word to word2vec's index, I pad left all 0s to missing word or if word is not in dictionary up to max number of words. maybe this is the reason why the accuracy is bad? because 0 represents kernel32 in dictionary?

So I might need to fill with other values by some rules: if word is not in dictionary, fill value -1, if word is missing pad right with -2?

Comment: Since the embeddings have only `mask_zero` to ignore values. Keep the 0 for "end of the sequence". Make other indices for words not in dictionary, all greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. The word2vec dictionary has index 0 maps to a word 'kernel32'. So in order to use mask_zero in embedding layer, when I build the embedding_weights, I need to change code from embedding_weights[value.index, :] = model[word]  to embedding_weights[value.index+1, :] = model[word] so that the index 0's vector in embedding_weights is all Zeros? and it will be ignored if mask_zero = True.  For the words not in dictionary words, what vector I should give them, can I make their indices the last index of embedding_weights which is all Zeros, something like [0,0,0,0... max_feature_length]?

Comment: You don't have to build embedding weights. Let the model train the weights itself. You only need a dictionary of indices.

Comment: Yes. The weight/vector is generated by word2vec model. Once I have the word2vec model, I map the indices to the vector of it's word in dictionary by embedding weights matrix.  And when prepare the training data, I also convert the actual words into the indices, so that it's consistent with the index in embedding weights matrix. For the missing word, I pad them into 0/Zero. For the OOV, what indices value I should assign them to, and what the vector I should assign to this indices?  I googled and it seems that I could assign a randoms generated weights for those OOV?

Comment: No vector. You don't need a word2vec model. The embedding layers are already a word2vec model themselves. You need just a dictionary of indices, like: `'kernel32' = 1`, `'user32' = 2`, etc. You're going to input the indices only. The model will take care of the rest. The embedding layers will automatically create vectors (you only define the size of these vectors), and will automatically train these vectors to the best result.

Comment: Gotcha. What I should do for out of vocabulary word, what indices I should assign them to?

Comment: There is no rule. You can gather the words in a list, check if the word already exists in the list, if not, append it. Any weird symbol you have you can decide to add to the end of the list, such as "other words". As long as the index is different from the actual existing words, it's ok. Then you just get the indices that they ended up in the list and sum 1 (to reserve the 0 for padding).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. If I want to make existing data a 3d structure, say: training data input_indices=[num_files * each file 1000 API calls, * each API call + parameters], for each word I find the indices in dictionary and put it into the input_indices. However, because the embedding_weight contains each word's indices/index and their vector, the current structure of embedding layer doesn't work with the structure of input training data, in this case, what should I do to make it work?  One way I tried is remove the embedding layer,  put the vector of each word instead of indices into training data.

Comment: See the edit in my answer about how to prepare the inputs.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks you so much. The current data is quite large and was generate in a way that module, function and parameters are concatenated all together with a line-terminator. Previously when I convert input was 2D array indices [number_files * each file's module + API + parameters in one line], and use embedding layer, the model can run but accuracy is not good.

Comment: I will try to re-generate the data so that 3 type of data could be separated. but it may take longer time.  
If based on current data structure,  I convert them into 3D array that they are in a 3D array contains module, API and parameters all together. The 3D array is [num_files * each file has 1000 depth API calls, * each API call + parameters] contains each word's indices as input_indices. But when use embedding layer and this 3D input indices, there is an error that embedding layer can't look up the indices in 3D input to find it's vector. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I will definitely try your suggestions later on. The problem is that to generate the data again to separate 3 input would take longer time due to some backend issue and data size is huge. So I wonder based on the current data structure, if there is a quick fix for improvement :)

Comment: Not sure I understand your data, but isn't it the same thing I did with the "parameters input"? They're 3D because they're "files x lines x params". So in the model I did a reshape before and after the embedding. --- Your input seems the same: "files x lines x wordsInLine". Try the same reshape method.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you so much again. I will learn and try reshape.